# MySQL SELECT everything into one big string (columns and rows)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a big MySQL SELECT query, that I need to convert into one string only, so I can make an UPDATE out of it, without having to use two separate querys. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume we have a SELECT query that returns this result:

[image]

How do I convert all of it into something like this :

```
1,Bob,20;2,Adam,30;3,Steve,40;
```

That I can use to UPDATE some other table with ?

Knowing that both the number of columns and rows can change and are not static. (very important ! **Especially the columns**!). How can I pull this off ? I don't think `CONCAT()` can help in this situation.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanky ou.

Answer (score 18):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT group_concat(concat(id, ',', name, ',', age) separator ';')
FROM test
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/915557/9

Comment: I can not choose concat because the columns can change, and are so long. I need something that can automatically read all the columns from a SELECT query. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that! I can't think of any other way right now.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
SET @colnames := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME, '\', \'') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'test' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db');
SET @query := CONCAT('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(', @colnames, 'SEPARATOR \';\') FROM test');
PREPARE STMT FROM @query;
EXECUTE STMT;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not looking for a separate query to do this task, this can be achieved from a query itself. You can insert into another table and update a table as well depending on a query select result.

Assuming that your original table is table_from and you need to copy it into table_to
(It further assumes table_from contains above mentioned original data),

To insert content into table_to from table_from,

```
insert into table_to(id, name, age)
  select tf.id, tf.name, tf.age
  from table_from tf
  where tf.id != 3;
```

If you pass the exact number of columns for the table you can omit columns name and just pass the values which in your case will be useful.

```
insert into table_to
  select tf.id, tf.name, tf.age
  from table_from tf
  where tf.id != 3;
```

To update content of table_to from table_from,

```
update table_to tt, table_from tf
  set tt.name = "Chandi"
  where tt.id = tf.id and tf.id = 1;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af43a/1

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a .csv file. Micheal McLaughlin has some very good walk throughs on how to do this. 
http://michaelmclaughlin.info/db1/lesson-7-aggregation/mysql-csv-upload/